# Express and MongoDB problem with insertedCount

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a problem using "insertedCount" in MongoDB in a NodeJS project. After the "insertOne()" the const assigned doesn't let me read the insertedCount value returning an "undefined". I attach my app.js code:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dbURI = "mongodb+srv://xxxx:xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.mongodb.net/xxxx?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(dbURI, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

let blogDB, articoliCollection;

//Create
app.get("/nuovo-articolo", async (req, res) => {
  const articolo = {
     titolo: "Titolo articolo 1",
     testo: "Testo articolo 1",
     autore: "Andrea",
     tag: ["node.js", "javascript", "mongodb"]
  };
  const ris = await articoliCollection.insertOne(articolo);
  if(ris.insertedCount === 1){
    res.send("Nuovo articolo inserito correttamente!");
  }
});

//Read
app.get("/articolo", (req, res) => {});

//Update
app.get("/modifica-articolo", (req, res) => {});

//Delete
app.get("/cancella-articolo", (req, res) => {});

async function run(){
  await mongoClient.connect();
  console.log("Siamo connessi a MongoDB Atlas");
  app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server in ascolto sulla porta 3000..."));
  blogDB = mongoClient.db("blog");
  articoliCollection = blogDB.collection("articoli");
}

run().catch(err => console.log("Errore connessione: " + err));
```

Using an insertMany passing 2 documents it goes inside the if (changing the value of the equal in 2) but with a simple insertOne in the const ris I have no insertedCount.
In the DB the document is stored with no problems. How can I use the insertedCount with insertOne? The console.log(ris.insertedCount) keep giving me "undefined".

With the code I wrote I cannot reach the res.send in the if.

Tnx, Andrea.

Comment: `insertOne` returns an acknowledgement and the `_id` value of the newly inserted document. Note that `insertOne` can insert one document only (or else it fails).

Comment: Tnx for the answer. The problem is that I cannot use “insertedCount” with “insertOne”. Is there any way?

Comment: You can use `insertmany` and insert one document in it. Then you get the `insertedCount`.

Comment: I was following a step by step course online on udemy and the problem started cause the teacher used the couple insertOne-insertedCount. I don’t know why it doesn’t work to me

Comment: Your code worked as it is (only thing I changed is the `dbURI` to my own).  I see the message "Nuovo articolo inserito correttamente!" in the browser and the document is inserted in the "articoli" collection of "blog" database.

Comment: I don’t know what is going on so. My browser keeps loading and loading cause it never reach the send(). I put a console.log(“Test”) inside the of too and is not shown. And the reason is that ris.insertedCount is “undefined”.

Comment: May be your connection url is not correct. Are you able to connect to the MongoDB from another tool like Compass or `mongo` shell?

Comment: I didn't but I solved using insertMany and passing an array with just a document inside. With insertMany I have the insertedCount value so I can check everything I need with that. If you want to reply with this to the question I can confirm the answer. You told me to use this way.

Comment: I stumbled on the same problem

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70606262/how-can-i-use-insertedcount-in-mongodb
you can change the check to  ```if(ris.acknowledged)``` (boolean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a callback function along with InsertOne
like

```
modal.insertOne(doc, function(err, res){
if(err) console.log("error",err)
else
 console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: The async/await way works good. If I try a console.log(ris) it returns an object with ‘acknowledged’ and ‘insertedId’. I need to retrieve an insertedCount too.