# How can i use insertedCount in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When I execute the route "/ new-article" the article is added to the database, but the server does not send a reply to the client. I noticed that this stems from the fact that the constant ris has no insertedCount property and this causes the if condition to never be true, preventing you from executing res.send ()

```
app.get('/new-article', async (req, res) => {
    const articolo = {
        titolo: 'Titolo articolo 1',
        testo: 'Testo articolo 1',
        autore: 'Leonardo',
        tag: ['node.js', 'javascript', 'mongoDB']
    }
    const ris = await articoliCollection.insertOne(articolo);

    if(ris.insertedCount === 1) {
        res.send('Nuovo articolo inserito correttamente')
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using mongoose? There is no `insertOne` method apart from the mongoDB console

Comment: @LucaKiebel He is using the official driver, not mongoose.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/classes/Collection.html#insertOne

Answer (score 1):

There is no `insertedCount` from `Collection.insertOne()`. Instead, there are `acknowledged` and `insertedId`. [Doc(InsertOneResult)](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/interfaces/InsertOneResult.html)

`insertedCount` is from `Collection.insertMany()` [Doc(InsertOneResult)](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/interfaces/InsertOneResult.html)

You can read more from the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/modules.html) or use typescript to help you know more about the models.